# How do you list instance names for SQL Server when you have the server name?

Tags: .net, sql-server, instance

there can be multiple instances of sql server on a machine. I'm trying to identify every instance of sql server engine running on any given REMOTE machine. all the other answers in other questions ONLY address local machine.

I have seen `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` and it searches a network, I know the computer I want to search.

I have seen `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers` but it requires the 'instance name' which is what I'm looking for

How do you interrogate a machine for SQL Server instance info with .net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all instances of sql server programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363215/find-all-instances-of-sql-server-programmatically)

Comment: you should be able to use the answer to that question to enumerate instances on a specific machine.  does that help?

Comment: I see the answer and there's nowhere to identify what machine you want to interrogate, it's only for local machine

Comment: `foreach (var machine in activeMachines)` -- if you look at the code above this line, you'll see that `activeMachines` is a list of computer names.  if you get rid of the `foreach` loop and just do `string machine = "my computer name";`, it should be what you need

Comment: took another look, all it does is signify sql server is running, i need instance info which that does not give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog shows how to list instances of sql server installed on a machine `using System.ServiceProcess;`

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/03/07/how-to-detect-sql-server-instances-features-installed-on-a-machine/

the missing key for me was that the `ServiceController.GetService()` static method has an overload that takes a string 'servername'

```
class InstanceInfoRetriever
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetInstanceNames(string serverName)
        {
            var servicenames = new[] { "MSSQL", "SQL Server" };
            var services = ServiceController.GetServices(serverName);
            var sqlservices = services.Where(s => servicenames.Any(n => s.ServiceName.Contains(n)));
            return sqlservices.Select(s => s.ServiceName);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Dim dt as dataTable= SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()

For each dr as datarow in dt.Select("[ServerName] = '" & strServername & "'")

Msgbox(string.Concat(dr("ServerName"), "\\", dr("InstanceName"))))

NEXT
```

Where `strServername` is the machine name

Or try using Linq

```
Dim lst as List(of string) = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources().where(Function(x) x.servername = strServername).Select(Function(y) y.Servername & "\" & y.Instancename).ToList()
```

Comment: can't do this, too resource consuming, and not full proof, we have a LARGE network

Comment: Edited my answer. Try using Linq